# A simple cycle with text instead numbers

Tags: graphs, circles

can somebody help me to replace numbers to any text in the following graph:

```
% A simple cycle
% Author : Jerome Tremblay
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def \n {8}
\def \radius {3cm}
\def \margin {8} % margin in angles, depends on the radius

\foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
{
  \node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$\s$};
  \draw[->, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
    arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

thanks for any help

Comment: `\foreach \s/\t in {1/re, 2/place,3/by,4/any,5/text,6/you,7/like,8/here}
 {\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {\t};...` But what exactly do you need this for? Seems as if this is not the right code for your purpose...

Comment: This is the only graph that looks exactly like I want it to. The numbers would be replaced with:

Comment: This is the only graph that looks exactly like I want it to. The numbers would be replaced with short sentences like: 1. Die Welt ist ein Garten, dessen Zaun die Dynastie ist; 2. Die Gerechtigkeit ist etwas Übliches, wodurch das Heil der Welt garantiert ist; and so on. I'm not really into latex, so if You know other way to make that kind of graph I'll be really grateful.

Comment: Do they have to be circled? Do they need to have the same radius? Do you need bend arrows? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you are exactly after, but you can use a `smartdiagram` like this one:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}    
\begin{document}  

\begin{center}
\smartdiagramset{module shape=circle,
circular distance=6cm,
text width=2cm,
arrow tip=to}
\smartdiagram[circular diagram]{%
1. Die Welt ist ein Garten,
2. Die Gerechtigkeit ist etwas Übliches, 
3. wodurch das Heil der Welt garantiert ist,
4. Die Welt ist ein Garten, 
5. Die Gerechtigkeit ist etwas Übliches, 
6. wodurch das Heil der Welt garantiert ist,
7. Die Welt ist ein Garten, 
8. dessen Zaun die Dynastie ist
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Or, you can set a mono-color like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}    
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\smartdiagramset{module shape=circle, 
uniform color list=gray!60 for 8 items,
circular distance=6cm,
text width=2cm,
arrow tip=to}
\smartdiagram[circular diagram]{%
1. Die Welt ist ein Garten,
2. Die Gerechtigkeit ist etwas Übliches, 
3. wodurch das Heil der Welt garantiert ist,
4. Die Welt ist ein Garten, 
5. Die Gerechtigkeit ist etwas Übliches, 
6. wodurch das Heil der Welt garantiert ist,
7. Die Welt ist ein Garten, 
8. dessen Zaun die Dynastie ist
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're unexpectedly kind for me! I lost 6 hours trying to do something like that. Thank You. Just one notice: can I make it mono coloured?

Comment: @dave Please see my update.

Comment: Last thing. How to make a caption for this? I used caption package in the preamble and wrote \caption{Abb.1...} just before "\end{center}, but it's not working. I'm using Gummi with newest PPA.